# Next.js Passing Data from Custom App into the Page's getServerSideProps

Tags: next.js

I am trying to pass some data from custom _app.js page to the page's getServerSideProps. Is there anyway to do this?

[Custom._app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLj0H.png)

[Page.getServerSideProps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNwy2.png)

You advices would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Best Regards.

Comment: Please post relevant code as text, not an image. Unlike images, text can be easily copied and searched.

Comment: Resolved here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65738465/pass-data-prop-from-app-js-to-getserversideprops-in-a-page-nextjs-latest-v

Comment: Is the issue solved ?