# Pass data (prop) from _app.js to getServerSideProps in a page - NextJS, latest version

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have a custom `_app.js`:

```
  const Layout = ({ children }) => (children);

  const app = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {

    pageProps.baseUrl = 'some url';

    return (
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    )
};
```

And a page:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ req, query, res, baseUrl }) { 
// baseUrl is undefined and an error, if I am using it with destructiring

  console.log(req) // There is no baseUrl

  return { props: { ..... } }
}
```

I want to set that `pageProps.baseUrl= 'some url';` in `_app.js` and use it in page components including `getServerSideProps`, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

For now, I have created a file, which contains all global values like this:

```
let store = {};

const globalStore = {};

globalStore.set = (key, value) => {
    store = { ...store, [key]: value };
}

globalStore.get = (key) => {
    return store[key];
}


export default globalStore;
```

Then in `_app.js` import it and set a value:

```
const app = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
    globalStore.set('baseUrl', 'some url 1');
    globalStore.set('baseUrl2', 'some url 2');

    return (
        <Layout>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

import the file in  `pages/index.js` and inside the component or `getServerSideProps`:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ req, query, res }) {

    console.log('in getServerSideProps');
    console.log(globalStore.get('baseUrl'));
    console.log(globalStore.get('baseUrl2'));
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, in this particular case, it's ok to use constants here instead of props.

#### Proposed solution

In constants.js:

```js
export const BASE_URL = 'some url';
```

And in your page:

```js
import * as Constants from '../path/to/constants';

export async function getServerSideProps({ req, query, res }) { 
  // use Constants.BASE_URL here

  return { props: { ..... } }
}
```

#### Why won't props work the way you want them to?

Your page component and the getServerSideProps method you export from the file are separate, and are executed at different times. Rendering your  component does not call getServerSideProps. I believe the order in Next.js is like this:

1. A request is made at a route.
2. Next.js looks at the file in `pages/` for the corresponding route
3. Next.js will run the appropriate method based on the execution context (on a server render, getServerSideProps)
4. Next.js renders the App component, passing it the pageProps provided from getServerSideProps
5. The App component renders the Page component

In this case, you have created a paradox. Think about how the props flow:

1. getServerSideProps runs, returns a pageProps object
2. App component renders, containing the pageProps object passed from getServerSideProps
3. Page component renders, passed the pageProps

If getServerSideProps is responsible for creating the pageProps object, it can't also be passed that object as an argument.

Comment: Thx for the good explanation, but it is a dynamic value. There are different domains, which points to the same NextJS app. I can do that in each `getServerSideProps` (set the value, but not get) , but it is better practice to set it once and use it everywhere. You can check my solution, I am not sure is it the best.

Comment: Honestly your solution looks good considering what you're trying to do -- also, if I have this right, and you're serving one app at multiple domains, I think it might also help you to modify the Request object using server middleware, doing something like `req.domain = 'whatever my domain is'`, then you can have access to that value inside your `getServerSideProps` function to differentiate the context the app is running in